# Can I customize the alert emails sent from Azure Application Insights ?

Tags: email, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a couple apps using ONE and when there is an exception it is not shown in the email specifically which app is causing the problem. Is there some way to add info to the email ? I have the info in the exception . I just need it to appear in the email

```
   public void TrackNonFatalExceptions(Exception ex)
    {
        var dictExceptionProperties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "App", "EncompassRequestDocs" } };
        _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex, dictExceptionProperties, null);
    }
```

Comment: Nope. Tthre is no option to edit/change alert e-mail templates. However, the question is why you use the same AI account for different Apps?! The idea of AI is that is handles a single APP. It has also pretty neat "Application Map" feature which tracks external dependencies,  so if you have such need, you can still have all your apps linked to different AI Accounts and have global picture.

Comment: The reason I put them all in one is because I could not find an easy way to get them all on one dashboard in POWER BI if they were all their own. So I figured I would combine them and prefix the events with the app name.. But maybe ill go back to giving them all their own key if getting an email that contains the name of the program that caused the exception is the most important thing

Comment: You can use .NET SDK or REST API to get information about alert rules programmatically, and create your own template https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn931945.aspx https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Insights/.

Comment: Question [create programmatically application insights alert with webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588160/create-programmatically-application-insights-alert-with-webhook) may be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to customize alert emails sent from Azure Application Insights. How Can I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805266/i-want-to-customize-alert-emails-sent-from-azure-application-insights-how-can-i)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to customize the mails right now.

<s>There's a uservoice suggestion here:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/5894710-application-insights-daily-weekly-monthly-digest</s>  Update: This UserVoice instance is no longer available.

which *might* cover what you want.

more likely what you want/need is a way to query your own data programatically and generate the data however you want, in mail/dashboard/etc, which would be covered by a separate planned suggestion  <s>here:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/4999529</s>  ( Update: This UserVoice instance is no longer available.)