# I want to customize alert emails sent from Azure Application Insights. How Can I do it?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

Is there any way to give our own email template for AI alerts notification.

Below is my alarm raising code.
    telemetry.TrackMetric("Alarm", 3);

And I set Metric-> Alarm in my AI. Now I want to customize the email template.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848725/configure-email-template-for-azure-alerts?rq=3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to customize the alert template.  you could suggest this as a feature on the [application insights uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/) site.

However, you could do it by having the [alert have a webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-webhooks-alerts), and that webhook could do queries using the [public REST api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/), etc to generate whatever content and send emails (or post to slack, or whatever) that way?