# Configure Email Template for Azure Alerts

Tags: azure, email

Is there a way, I can configure the email template for Azure alerts. I have created an email alert for a metric and I need to send a custom email when the metric value cross the threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to customize the email template for Azure alerts.  As a workaround, you can configure a webhook on Azure Alert so that you can process the alert signal with your custom code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-webhooks-alerts