# Select specific columns for application insight alert email

Tags: azure-application-insights

When receiving emails from application insights everything is included in the mail. Is it possible to only show specific columns?

[image]

Comment: Can you attach an screenshot?

Comment: Yes of course. As you can see I dont want the details column and many of the others columns in the status mail.

Comment: The column you mean "timestamp" / "problemId" / "type" etc.? Ok, got it, I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes. As the email is very hard to read I would like only to show outerMessage.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not supported :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, customization of the alert email is not supported.

There is a [user feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management/suggestions/30932506-customize-alert-email) to track this issue.

Here is [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46868954/10185816) by using webhook, but I didn't try it. You can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for following up. Appreciated.